# Installing windows 8 on Ubuntu 12.10 with windows 8 already installed

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

I don't know that if it sounds confusing but what I want to do is that install windows 8 along with Ubuntu 12.10 (already installed). I have windows 8 previously installed as well and I want to overwrite it. Is it possible to do so? How can I do this without using a USB or a DVD?

Comment: which one is preinstalled on your pc (windows or ubuntu)?

Comment: @AvinashRaj both of them.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu Guess you need to format the original Win8 before installing the new Win8 there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install it without a USB or a DVD. You need to make an empty partition (you can use gparted to do that) with the windows 8 DVD contents and boot from it. I think this step is much harder than using a DVD or a USB drive but anyways that's how to do it without them.

You *do* need to format the current win 8 partition. You can do that also using gparted or I think you can do that directly when you're installing windows 8; It should ask you whether you want to format the old windows 8 and then reinstall it.

That's pretty much it! ask me about anything you don't understand. (like for example: what I mean by "booting from the partition" or how to do it).